# Wrong collection error when deploying gcloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I run this function deployment command (Gcloud CLI)

```
gcloud functions deploy function_name \
        --runtime python37 \
    --trigger-resource="gs://<bucket-name>/files/**/*.json" \
    --trigger-event=google.storage.object.finalize
```

I am trying to deploy a cloud function that triggers when an object is uploaded to a directory in google storage.

Every deployment I have tried, in all their variations, has failed due to one of the errors below.

The above CLI deployment command fails with:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) wrong collection: expected [storage.objects], got [storage.buckets], for path [gs:///files/**/*.json]

Out of curiosity, I tried using this trigger event (though, I've seen no support for it):

```
--trigger-event=google.storage.buckets.finalize
```

When I use it, and some other variations, this error appears:
Problems:

> event_trigger.resource: GCS bucket resource gs:///files/**/*.json does not match the expected pattern, which is projects/{project}/buckets/{bucket}

**Other Things I Tried**

1. gen2 deployment with the appropriate gen2 trigger event name (FAILED)
2. gcloud storage ls <wildcard_bucket path> to make sure I was getting the files expected from this path (SUCCESS)
3. Checked I have permission access to write, create, delete storage objects (SUCCESS)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use object path wildcards in a Cloud Storage trigger to select which files apply to the trigger.  From the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage):

> When you specify a Cloud Storage trigger for a function, you choose an event type and specify a Cloud Storage bucket. Your function will be called whenever a change occurs on an object (file) within the specified bucket.

The trigger is invoked on any object within the bucket.  If you don't want that behavior, you must write code in your trigger to check the path and decide if you want the trigger to continue.

You might want to follow along with the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage) to see how it works.

Comment: I'm still working through this, and see it might be possible by combining an eventarc trigger with a gen2 cloud function. Does this work?  

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/eventarc#gcloud  
https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/path-patterns. 

I haven't gotten it to totally work yet. I am still battling permission errors on deploying the new gcloud function with the eventarc parameters built in. But right now, the eventarc trigger seems to accept wildcard values in its path.

Comment: I've never used that.  If you have a question about EventArc, you should post a new question explaining what you're trying to do with it and what isn't working the way you expect.